# Get Firebase data ordered by value

Tags: firebase

Is there any way to get a certain number of Firebase data entries based on value. For example, if a certain entry had 100 children, each with a number value, would there be any way to request the children with the ten highest values?

EDIT: I realize that I could simply request the parent and iterate through the entire hierarchy of data until I find the ten with the largest value, but this would be a waste of user's data, especially if the parent contained thousands of children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you store the records, use [setPriority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/setwithpriority.html). Then you can retrieve ones with the highest value as follows:

```
firebaseRef.child.limit(10).on(...);
```

Or you could paginate or grab a specific set as follows:

```
firebaseRef.endAt(250).limit(10).on(...);
```

Comment: So I should set the priority the same as the value?

Comment: In the case that the value is a primitive that exactly matches the criteria you want to sort/query on, yes.

Comment: Seems kind of redundant, although I guess it will work. Am I using Firebase in a way that wasn't intended? Would I be better off finding an alternative backend?

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable way to use Firebase. Some duplication is going to take place. It's the nature of fast data storage (it happens every time you create an index in SQL, for instance).

Answer (score 5):

With firebase you are dealing with a nosql database. When using a nosql database, generate your reports when you write the data, not when you read it.

eg. For the case you mentioned, maintain another object that always contains the top ten records (or pointers to them).

Every time you write a record to the database check with the top ten list, if the record belongs there too, in which case do what is necessary.

This approach is faster and more efficient than iterating through a database.

Comment: good post about this from firebase: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html

Comment: I like that solution for that specific case, but let's say I wanted the top ten values for records whose identifier started with a specific letter. I was looking to implement a sort of search that returned the top ten items for a given query. It seems like this solution only works if I only care about a limited number of top ten lists.

Comment: That was just an example. The idea is to build your own index as you write data to the database if the indexing capabilities of the database do not suit your purpose.